# PiCamera vs VideoCapture

Tags: python, opencv, picamera

So I have a project that requires Computer Vision (video stream). But when I want to try my Pi Camera (not USB), there's two method that I can use. They are `PiCamera.capture_continuous` and `cv2.VideoCapture.read()`.

Both of these methods do well... But I'm wondering is there any difference to use one over another? Is there some performance issue with opencv's implementation? I found that if I want to use opencv, [someone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37530016/6241697) said I must activate the driver with `modprobe bcm2835-v4l2`. But in my RPi, I don't need to do that... Is that a latest firmware autoloaded the driver? Or the OpenCV did autoload the driver?

I also found that [someone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27956100/6241697) said I can't use VideoCapture for this CSI camera, but that said 4 years ago. Here I can use it with no problem. Is this updated on the newest firmware or OpenCV?

In case if you are wondering, I'm using newest OpenCV 4.1.0, cross compiled myself.

Thanks,